# Props not being passed when using custom document for styled components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, next.js

I'm trying to use styled components with next.js.  I've added the babel plugin and added a custom `_document.js`.  That all seems to be working fine.

However, when I try and use `isomorphic-unfetch` to `getInitialProps` into the page, the request returns data, but it doesn't make it into Props.

For `_document.js` I'm using the code from the next.js site [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js) and have also tried a slightly different version from [here](https://dev.to/aprietof/nextjs--styled-components-the-really-simple-guide----101c) which I also saw on the next.js docs site at some point.

My test page looks like this (also from the next.js [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)):

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

export default class MyPage extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
        const userAgent = req ? req.headers['user-agent'] : navigator.userAgent
        return { userAgent }
    }

    render() {

            return (
                <div>
                  Hello World {this.props.userAgent}
                </div>
              )
    }
}
```

I also have an `_app.js` that looks like this:

```js
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import Page from '../components/Page';

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Page>
          <Component />
        </Page>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

And `Page.js` just has some styled components and a theme with a component that looks like this:

```js
class Page extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <StyledPage>
                    <GlobalStyle />
                    <Meta />
                    <Header />
                    {this.props.children}
                </StyledPage>
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default Page;
```

I feel like it's something to do with the new _document.js or _app.js not passing the props down somehow.

Clearly I'm pretty new to next.js, so apologies if it's something stupid.  In the meantime, I'll keep plugging away to get a better understanding of what's going on.  I wanted to ask in parallel here since I'm under some time pressure for this project.

Many thanks for any thoughts you might have.

Comment: You can try adding `<Page {...this.props}>` in `App.js` to pass down the props from `App.js` to `Page.js`

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely spot on.  I spent far too long looking at _document.js instead of _app.js.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Not long after posting, I worked out the issue. I guess posting on SO helps to understand the issue.

Essentially it was `_app.js` which was the problem, not `_document.js` as I had initially expected.

I needed to add `pageProps` to `_app.js` so that they were propagated down to the page:

```js
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import Page from '../components/Page';

class MyApp extends App {

  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {};
    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }
    return { pageProps };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Page>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Page>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```